# wxpython AUI panels dockable but not floatable

Tags: macos, wxpython

I'm having some undesired behavior with movable panels in wxpython. I'm using the wxpython Cocoa build 2.9.2.3 for Python 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.6.7. I'm importing wx.aui and trying to create dockable panels.

I have a panel that I've created a wx.aui.AuiManager on and have added two panels, one on top and one on below. For both of them I have disabled the close button. Right now, the panels can be dragged into different dockable positions on the frame or off of the frame to create a floating window. This window shows up as the Mac native MiniFrame with a disabled close button. I do not want users to be able to separate the panels from the main frame.

I have passed .Floatable(False) to each pane's PaneInfo, but this won't allow the panels to be moved around at all, even if I pass a .Dockable(True)

Can I have panes in AUI that are dockable and movable, but not floatable?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, I want to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do that or not. It may be a limitation of wx.aui. You should ask on the wxPython mailing list. Or you could try the mostly drop-in replacement: wx.agw.aui (http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/aui_module.html#aui). It fixes a bunch of bugs in the default wx.aui and is written in pure Python.